# How do I use OAuth 2.0 just for authentication for Google?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0

The [OAuth2 PHP client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2) code is awesome. It gives great examples on how to use OAuth 2 with Google APIs. The problem is that I only want to use OAuth 2 for authentication NOT for authorization. I've looked around in the API for something that just authenticates but I can't find the right class.

**How do I configure the Google PHP client to only authenticate via OAuth?**

I considered just authenticating the client (i.e. `$client->authenticate($_GET['token'])) but that's not ideal because the user is still asked to authorize access to different resources. I don't want to see their email, picture, etc. I just want Google to verify that they are who they say they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, *[OAuth is an open standard for authorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth)* and not for authentication!

Most providers however give you the chance to query a users profile, so you can authenticate the user. Without the access to his profile data, especially his *user id*, you can not achieve this.

See Google's documentation for [obtaining the user's profile information for login](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#userinfocall).

Comment: There is a section in the Google API documentation that says "OAuth:Login" which led me to believe that there was a way to use OAuth for authentication only.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to use authetication you have to use: OpenID / Federated Login.
See: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID